# getting cannot convert to male error in django?

Tags: django, export

I am trying to export the list of customers using django.

```
class Gender(models.IntegerChoices):
        FEMALE = 1, female_label
        MALE = 2, male_label

gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    db_column="Gender",
    verbose_name=gender_label,
    choices=Gender.choices,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
```

and I am calling in the export row like this:

```
customer.gender_label
```

and I am getting such an error ***Cannot convert 'Male' to Excel***

do you have any idea why this error is showing up?

***** update: customer.get_gender_display() solved my problem***

Comment: You call the attribute ba the field name, not the verbose_name `customer.gender`

Comment: verbose_name is human-readable name of a field, it's not used in queries and lookups

Comment: You can use `customer.get_gender_display()`.

Comment: customer.gender gives the values 1 and 2, but I want male and female options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the choice  display (so here the value for `female_label` and `male_label`) with the `.get_gender_display()` method, so:

```
customer.get_gender_display()
```

Indeed, as the [documentation on the **`.get_fieldname_display()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) says:

> For every field that has `choices` set, the object will have a
> `get_FOO_display()` method, where `FOO` is the name of the field. This
> method returns the “human-readable” value of the field.